# R - manipulate last rows depending on group and previous elements

Tags: r, dplyr

Im fairly new to R and struggling to find a solution for the following problem:
I have a tibble consisting of 3 columns. First column describes ids of stocks (e.g. ID1,ID2..), the second the Date of observation and third the corresponding return. (ID | Date | Return )

For tidying my dataset I need to delete all zero returns starting from end of sample period until i reach the first non zero return.
The following picture further visualises my issue.

[DatasetExample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5gVr.jpg)

In case of the example Dataset depicted above, I need to delete the yellow coloured elements.

Hence, one needs to first group by ID and second iterate over the table from bottom to top until reaching a non zero return.
I already found a way by converting the tibble into a matrix and then looping over each element but this apporach is rather naive and does not perform well on large datasets (+2 mio. observations), which is exactly my case.
Is there any more effcient way to achieve this aim? Solutions using dplyr would be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Kindly read these topics: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [Why not upload images of code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a `dplyr` solution. I believe it's a bit complicated, but it works.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, format = "%d.%m.%Y")) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  arrange(desc(Date), .by_group = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(flag = min(which(Return == 0)),
         flag = cumsum(Return != 0 & flag <= row_number())) %>%
  filter(flag > 0) %>%
  select(-flag) %>%
  arrange(Date, .by_group = TRUE)
## A tibble: 7 x 3
## Groups:   ID [2]
#     ID Date       Return
#  <int> <date>      <dbl>
#1     1 2020-09-20  0.377
#2     1 2020-09-21  0    
#3     1 2020-09-22 -1.10 
#4     2 2020-09-20  0.721
#5     2 2020-09-21  0    
#6     2 2020-09-22  0    
#7     2 2020-09-23  1.76
```

**Test data creation code**

```
set.seed(2020)
df1 <- data.frame(ID = rep(1:2, each = 5), Date = Sys.Date() - 5:1, Return = rnorm(10))
df1$Date <- format(df1$Date, "%d.%m.%Y")
df1$Return[sample(1:5, 2)] <- 0
df1$Return[sample(6:10, 2)] <- 0
df1$Return[10] <- 0
```

Comment: Cheers!!! Thanks you so much for this fast and awesome solution.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a more elegant way but this could work:

```
split_data <- split(data,data$ID)

split_tidy_data <- lapply(split_data,function(x) x[1:which.max(x[,"Return"]!=0),])

tidy_data <- do.call(rbind,split_tidy_data)
```

Note: This only works if there is at least 1 "Return" which is not equal 0

Comment: Thanks !!! Unfortunately this assumption cannot be guranteed. Nevertheless, thanks for your great help bro